# Calculation of Document hashCode in SQL or PL/SQL for CLOBs

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hash, plsql

I am looking for help in replicating Java's String.hashCode() function in SQL. It is computed as:

`s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]`

I could do it easily with a java program, but I have a lot of CLOBs to process and I am thinking (perhaps incorrectly?) that the update would run faster on the server without dealing with the network overhead. Does anybody have such a function?

Some requirements are that:

1. It be in SQL or Oracle's PL/SQL since I am doing this on Oracle (sadly)
2. It work on CLOBs, not just varchars
3. It can handle large CLOBs (>4K)

Also it doesn't have to use java hashCode(), it can use a different hashing algorithm like MD5SUM if it is easier to do. I will need to update about a million records and will be using the hash to indicate if the source document (or conversion process) results in a changed document.

Comment: *Why* do you need this? Usually it would be better to use a non-platform-specific hash, e.g. MD5 of the UTF-8, or a more secure hash still. Even if you do need this, you should consider "developer time taken" as well as "elapsed time taken" - if you can implement it in half an hour via "pull from database, calculate hash codes locally, push" then does it matter if it takes all weekend to run?

Comment: I don't actually need it to be platform specific, any reasonable hash I can calculate easily in Java (MD5, SHA) and also calculate in the database will work. Security isn't an issue, I am using this field as part of unique constraint (along with document source and source document id) to detect changes in the source document due to either source document changes that don't update the source document identifier or changes in the source document conversion process that result in a novel CLOB. So if you have a solution with MD5 I am happy to see it.

Comment: I would investigate what Oracle supports then. I wouldn't be at all surprised if it supported MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256 etc. Those would be much better than using Java's hash code.

Comment: The other complication I just realized may be an issue is that Java's strings are native UTF-16 I believe and I am using some Oracle 11g default Western Charset or something like that for the CLOB. I need something that can give consistent answers for both. I guess if I stick to computing it on the database side I don't care.

Comment: *"using this field as part of unique constraint"*. Hashes are not guaranteed to be unique for different source material, so using hash in a unique constraint is very troublesome.

Comment: You should think of the strings as just "text". You need to apply an encoding to get to a binary representation, which is what hashes like MD5 require. That's easy to do in Java, and I suspect it's easy to do in Oracle too.

Comment: @Andreas: Indeed. *Less* of a problem with SHA-256 for example, but definitely not a good idea for just `hashCode`.

Comment: @Andreas - it should not be a problem since I am using document source (name of database), source database identifier and source version as part of the key. The hash is only relevant when the source document (say a PDF file) is converted to a CLOB by say a new version of the Tika library and has a different CLOB now. If I was *ONLY* using the hash as a unique constraint I would agree with you that it may be problematic.

Comment: Looks like I found a potential solution that is Oracle specific: ```CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_md5sum_clob_fn( i_clob IN CLOB)
    RETURN RAW
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH
        (
            src => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(i_clob),
            typ => DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_MD5
        );
END;
``` I will see if this works once I have a user with access to DBMS_CRYPTO.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered ora_hash() in Oracle, but it looks like it only looks at the first 4K of the document. Instead I am using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_md5sum_clob_fn( i_clob IN CLOB)
    RETURN RAW
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH
        (
            src => i_clob,
            typ => DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_MD5
        );
END;
```

I also only give this non-null CLOBs otherwise there will be an error. It suffers from a few limitations:

1. I haven't tested if it looks past 4K
2. It is Oracle specific.

So I am not accepting my own answer yet. I'd love to see a database independent solution.

Comment: Please use indentation rather than triple-backtick for block code quoting in SO.